# trouble with angularjs ui-sref

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using tabset view in one of my pages.I have divided each tab into each html pages..and I'm loading them as templates using ui-sref.

```
<div class="white-bg animated fadeIn">

<div class="row s-t-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="tabs-container">

                <tabset class="tabs-left">
                    <tab id="tab1" heading="Job Preferences" ui-sref="user.education.jobs">

                         <div ng-include="'views/user/jobstab.html'"></div>

                    </tab>

                    <tab id="tab2" heading="Experience / Project Summary" ui-sref="user.education.experience">

                        <div ng-include="'views/user/experience.html'"></div>

                    </tab>

                    <tab id="tab3" heading="Educations / Certifications / Awards" ui-sref="user.education.certificate">

                        <div ng-include="'views/user/certificate.html'"></div>

                    </tab>
                </tabset>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It is working. I can load the three templates clicking on the tabs in home page.
but I have a button in each html page which on clicked should activate the state of the next tab...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-offset-9">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ui-sref="user.education.experience">Save &amp; Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

i.e if i click the above button it should activate the 'experience' tab.
I can see that the url in the address bar is changing when i click the button but not the view.

here's my stateprovider
    $stateProvider

```
    .state('index', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "views/common/content_user_navigation.html",
    })

    .state('landing', {
        url: "/landing",
        templateUrl: "views/landing.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Awarded Me Home', specialClass: 'landing-page' }
    })



    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/user/login.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Login' }
    })


    .state('user.profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        templateUrl: "views/user/user_profile.html",
    })

    .state('user.education', {
        url: "/education",
        templateUrl: "views/user/education1.html",
    })

    .state('user.education.jobs', {
        url: "/jobs",
        templateUrl: "views/user/jobstab.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Job Preferences' },

    })

    .state('user.education.experience', {
        url: "/experience",
        templateUrl: "views/user/experience.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Experience' },
    })

    .state('user.education.certificate', {
        url: "/certificate",
        templateUrl: "views/user/certificate.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Education' },
    })
```

Any idea about the problem?